# How to test Timer Service (EJBTimer) in JavaEE6 that runs every end of month

Tags: timer, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I was just wondering, what's the best way to test a JavaEE6 timer? For example, I have a job that runs every end of the month, or end of week :-?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you would test anything time-based: adjust your system clock, or test that the expected timeout looks reasonable (e.g., check that `getNextTimeout` returns a reasonable value).

Comment: It's been 4 years and I was still looking for a more elegant solution but I guess this would do :-)